# why does ipv6 coexist with ipv4 slow the load?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6, ipv4

My laptop have two network adapter:one is wired lan, while the other is wireless lan. Now I connect ipv6 using wired lan and ipv4 using wireless. The web page seems to get something wrong. It load slowly. However, if I disconnect one of the adapter(anyone of ipv4 or ipv6), the web page load fast as I expect. Why does the odd phenomenon occur?

Answer (score -2):

Because you are essentially specifying two gateways to the internet and the system does not know which one to use.  You could try this experiment:  remove the gateway setting from one of your two connections.  Now try loading the web page.  Everything will load fast.

Comment: but one is ipv4-only and the other is ipv6-only , I think system know that if packet is ipv4 then go ipv4 gateway, and go ipv6 if it's  ipv6 packet. what do you think?